# Equation of tangent plane to a parametrised surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surfaces, parametrization

I've got a problem trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with these question regarding finding the equation of the tangent plane to a parametrised surface.
A surface is parametrised by

$$x = u^2-v^2, \ \ \ \ y = u + v, \ \ \ \ z = u^2 + 4v$$

I know this is the parametrisation $$\Phi(u,v) = (u^2-v^2, \ u+v,\ u^2+4v)$$
Also, the surface is not smooth at $(u,v) = (2,-2)$

My problem is:

> What is the equation of the tangent plane to the surface at $\Big (\frac{-1}{4},\frac{1}{2},2 \Big) ?$

So far, I've done the following:

I set $$(u^2-v^2, \ u+v,\ u^2+4v) = \Big (\frac{-1}{4},\frac{1}{2},2 \Big)$$

So the system of equations becomes: 
$$ (1)\ \ \ u^2 - v^2 = \frac{-1}{4}$$
$$ (2)\ \ \ u + v = \frac{1}{2}$$ 
$$ (3)\ \ \ u^2 + 4v = 2$$

$(3) - 4 (2)$ $$\implies u^2 - 4u = 2-4(\frac{1}{2})$$
$$u^2-4u = 0$$
$$u = 0$$ or $$u = 4$$

Putting $u=0$ into (2), we get $v=\frac{1}{2}$, which is the correct and apparently only solution set $(u,v) = (0,\frac{1}{2})$.

But we also have $u=4$ which, when put into (2), gives another (incorrect) solution set of $(u,v) = (4,\frac{-7}{2})$

My question is:

> What exactly have I done wrong?

Cheers guys :)

Comment: Your second solution does not satisfy (1)

Comment: Why do you think you have done something wrong?

Comment: @Paul ok cheers :) i'll make sure to check all equations next time

Comment: @smcc I was getting more than one solution set for $u$ and $v$ but I should have checked the values of $u$ and $v$ for all equations

Comment: I thought you had identified it was incorrect (which it is, as Paul pointed out), but now I realize you must have only identified at is incorrect because it did not match the answer you were given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving

$$
S(u,v) = (u^2-v^2,u+v,u^2+4v)\\
p = (x,y,z)\\
p_0 = \left(-\frac 14,\frac 12,2\right)
$$

Solving

$$
S(u,v) = p_0 \Rightarrow \left(u = 0, v = \frac 12\right)
$$

now calling

$$
\vec t_u = S_u = (2u,1,2u)\\
\vec t_v = S_v = (-2v,1,4)\\
\vec n = \vec t_v\times\vec t_u = 2(u-2,4u+2u v, -u-v)
$$

at $p = p_0$ we have $\vec n = \vec n_0 = (-4,0,-1)$

and the tangent plane is

$$
(p-p_0)\cdot \vec n_0 = 0\Rightarrow z-4x+1=0
$$

Attached a plot showing the tangency and $\vec n_0$ in red.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in what you have done.
(3) is a parabola, (2) is a line : they can have $0,1 ,2$ points in common. In this case they have two as you found.
That one of these solutions does not satisfy (1) , that is perfectly ok, because otherwise the parametrization would be not univocal.